# Unable to boot the Laptop, Hard drive not responding

Tags: windows, boot

When I start the Laptop, the Toshiba logo pops followed by message, "Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key".

I tried to modify the BIOS setup to boot from USB, but the change option is not active. Also, I'm unable to move within the BOIS setup since I'm not getting any display.

I need suggestion that, how to fix the problem?

Comment: based on what you have presented, I'd suspect that the laptop harddisk has failed, rather than that your son "deleted" everything. windows cannot delete itself, so you have to boot from other media (which may be the case, but we would have expected you to mention it). you can't just accidentally do that kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try burning windows in a CD and try to boot from an USB CD/DVD drive. In my experience, PCs / laptops from pre 2010s have a hard time booting from USB drives.

Also, I don't have enough reputation to comment on stefcyp , but some bios have different keys to open boot menu, some have F9, F11, Supr, ... . Try pressing multiple times a key, and if it doesn't work, reboot and try another.

As a last resort, I would try a data recovery software and completely reinstall windows.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to change the boot mode ? Shouldn't you just change the boot device ? Optionnaly, you might not even need to go to the bios for that : many computer have a boot device selection menu accessible by pressing F8 during startup.

Answer (score 0):

To enter the boot menu, as soon as you power on your Toshiba laptop, press F12.
As long as you have the usb inserted you should then be able to select to boot from the usb device.